# Angular 8 filter : preserve line breaks on text area input

Tags: html, angular, input, filter, pipe

I trying to make a filter with angular 8 to preserve text line break on my text area input, the text input will be placed above an image :

```
<div class="form-group col-10">
          <span class="badge badge-theme mb-3">Message personnalisé</span>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" formControlName="personalizedMessage"
            rows="6"></textarea>

        </div>
<div class="col-6" style="margin-top: 35px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 card-container">
          <img src={{displayedImage}} alt="">
          <div class="message">
            <p ng-bind-html="personalizedMessage | linebreaks">{{giftCardForm.controls['personalizedMessage'].value}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'linebreaks'
})
export class LinebreaksPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(text: any): any {
    return text.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
  }

}
```

I'm new with angular and I'm not sure if the pipe is written good ! can some one help !

Comment: <p [innerHTML]="personalizedMessage | linebreaks"> </p>  - try this one

Comment: thanks @SaurabhYadav,   that's not working

Comment: check working demo

Comment: any luck with this, im trying to do the same thing and the demo below doesnt work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypmbqn)

Try this one in pipe:

```
 export class LinebreaksPipe implements PipeTransform {

      transform(value: string): string {
        return value.replace(/\\n/g, '<br />');
      }
    }
```

In template file:

```
<p [innerHTML]="profileForm.get('personalizedMessage').value | linebreaks">
```

Answer (score 18):

Working example for Angular with **Reactive forms**, if you want to use **template driven form** , use instead of `formControlName="message"` ---> `[(ngModel)]="message"`

1. Have a **textarea** where you put the input

**Example**

```
 <textarea placeholder="Message" formControlName="message" rows="3"></textarea>
```

2. Where you display it

`<div class="message" [innerHTML]="message">`

3. Style the container with

`.message { white-space: pre-wrap;}`

Comment: This is the simplest answer (to me) and works great.  You do not have to be using Reactive forms and it works well with PrimeNG p-textarea and displaying the output in a p-scrollPanel as well - it is a simple css solution.  Just remember that the carriage returns and line feeds actually exist (even if you can't see them) and by telling the display component that the text is pre-formatted you can see them as they were intended.

Comment: I liked this answer as it worked for me. I am using Angular 11 with PrimeNG version 11. The answer just worked!!